# NserviceBus MSMQ inputqueue with IP addresses

Tags: nservicebus

I am evaluating nservicebus and samples work on local server. app.config files in sample suggest to use queue@pcname for msmq configuration. My question is can IP addresses be used in circumstances where there is no DNS server?

BR
Niladri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, make sure you have 2.5 as this was a patch in the recent past.  Check the Github repo if you want to be really sure.

Comment: Thanks , I have 2.5 and will check out if it works with IP addresses , else have to repo....